# How do I float one image on top of another?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I've done some searching on this topic, but I can't seem to find an answer that's exactly what I'm looking for.
I'm trying to set up a banner ad (728 x 90) on my site so it is "laid over" a div with a background image. Therefore, if someone has an adblocker, they'll see an image that says "please disable your adblock" where the ad should be.

My current code is this:

```
<div style="float: left; background-image: url(../forum/banners/replacement.png); height: 90px; width: 728px; border: 1px solid black;">
</div>
<!-- BEGIN SMOWTION TAG - 728x90 - DO NOT MODIFY -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- ad code goes here -->
    </script>
<!-- END SMOWTION TAG - 728x90 - DO NOT MODIFY -->
```

However, this makes the ad show up under the div, instead of appearing 'overlaid' on it. How can I make it so that the ad and the div don't clip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position the parent `relative` and then the children `absolute`....

```
#Container {
    position: relative;
}

.Children {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px
    left: 0px
}
```

The absolute is "relative" to the parent - so the children will be 0px across and 0px down from the parent - ie overlaid

```
<div id="Container">
    <img class="Children" src="..."/>
    <img class="Children" src="..."/>
</div>
```

Comment: This did it! I had to set the height of the container div to be 91px and get rid of the border from the replacement image to make everything nice, but it worked out! Thanks!